# Predictive model to maximize sum of dependent variable

Tags: r, linear-regression, logistic-regression, prediction

I am trying to classify cars for a towing company. Junky  cars earn more when  sent to the junkyard, and the more valuable cars should earn more at the auction, despite the auction fee.  Creating a logistical regression that takes into account Make, Model, Mileage,  Year and Run status helps us improve the accuracy of which cars should go where, but a difficulty arises: Sometimes, a car that would be classified as junk can actually be an outlier, and sell for a lot of money. So to optimize our model, we don't really care that much whether we are right or wrong on an individual car, so much as we maximize our bottom line.
All of the models I have seen (Logistical regression, RF, linear regression) make predictions on a line by line basis.
What would be a good model to try and maximize the aggregate sum of the predictions?
Below is a reprex of my data, as well as basic code I used.
What I actually tried until now is to look at past data, and classify , in hindsight, what should have been done, based on prices that were earned in the auction vs available junk prices. I then ran a glm against that classification to predict the future. As mentioned above, my code improved the accuracy of our decisions, and would have sent more cars to junk correctly, but  some  that we classified as junk sold for so much in the auction that  it wasn't worth sending *any* to junk.
What is the proper way to approach this?

````
cars <- structure(list(YearOfCar = c(2009L, 2009L, 2003L, 2004L), Make = c("Hyundai", "Lexus", "Ford", "Toyota"), Model = c("Sonata", "GS 350", "F-250 Super Duty","Camry"), PickUpState = c("MN", "LA", "MA", "NJ"), Auction_Result = c(650,625,425, 1500), Auction_Fee = c(144.25, 373.54, 213.5, 187), Mileage = c(116120L, 198900L, 140241L, 312927L), Runs = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"),   junkyard_Offer = c(230L, 235L, 140L, 300L), Date = structure(c(17592,  17707, 17674, 17583), class = "Date")), row.names = 3:6, class = "data.frame")
cars$hindsight <- ifelse(cars$Auction_Result-cars$Auction_Fee>cars$junkyard_Offer,1,0)
glmodel <- glm(hindsight~Make+Model+Mileage+Runs, data = cars, family="binomial")
prediction <- predict(glmodel, cars, type = 'response')
prediction_classifier <-  if_else(prediction>.501,1,0)
cars$prediction_results <- ifelse(prediction_classifier==1, cars$Auction_Result-cars$Auction_Fee,cars$junkyard_Offer)```
````

Comment: Apparently you are not running into coding difficulties, but rather have a small dataset that doesn't allow the kind of analysis to spot what you are calling "outliers". You are running into difficulties because a binomial model is not well structured to allow weighting by the costs of "mistakes".  This is not the forum for seeking advice about how to improve modeling approaches. Either CrossValidated .com or the Quantitative Finance forums on stackexchange might be better.

Comment: Fair enough. I see why you don't like my language of outliers... The point is more about the costs of mistakes. Anyway, you clearly know more than most... Feel free to give it a shot! I have taken your advice and posted on CV as well. Thanks and keep well.

Comment: Lots of people think they can remove outliers to improve their predictions. Furthermore what you are calling 'outliers' are really the stuff you are hoping to also predict. So it would be better to think of them as there own category.

Comment: I tried to vrun the logistical regression to predict the outliers, but didn't help. I think I need to figure out a way to account for the costs of mistakes, holistically, like you described.

Comment: Yes and I've offered other advice as well.